# Firebase Error in Retrieving - Syntax Error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Stumbled on something odd and was wondering for some input. I have a dynamic child naming system and want to retrieve data. Now, when I try to input the dynamic naming of child it does not retrieve it however when I do it manually it does. I have debugged via print, and it seems to be working as well as other forms of observation. Any clue?

Assuming test = code test (to make it easier). Could it be the way the statements are wrote? The working one uses queryOrdered where as the other uses observe?

Working Type:

```
let refPosts = Database.database().reference().child("postsof"+"\(test)").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: "\(result)")
```

Does Not Work:

```
Database.database().reference().child("postsof"+"\(test)").observe(DataEventType.value)
```

Works Manually:

```
Database.database().reference().child("postsoftest").observe(DataEventType.value)
```

Edit:

**Print**: For all print statements, it shows as "postsoftest". This confirms that for the second example, "postsof"+" \ (test)" is being read correctly on the debugger as postsoftest, however does not retrieve the data as the other 2 examples.

**JSON**:

```
  "postsoftest": {
    "autoID": {
      "name": "jack"
      "link": "..."
    }
  },
```

Comment: We're gonna need a bit more information to be able to help here. Can you edit your question to include: 1) the code that you use to actually read and process the data, like the `print` you mention. 2) the output that you get for each of the resulting snippets. 3) the JSON of the database that you query (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for the response. I have made the following changes.

Comment: Please show the exact code and output for #1 and #2.  Paraphrasing it not good enough, as the devil may well be in the omitted details.